# How do I validate content from a CKEditor 5 editor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to figure out how I can validate content from the editor, for example, making sure the content is at least 200 characters in length. Normally, with a regular textarea, I can retrieve the value and validate it from there. From my understanding, it is not that easy with this.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple function that allows you count how many characters is inserted in the document.

```
/**
 * Returns length of the text inserted to the specified document.
 *
 * @param {module:engine/model/document~Document} document
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function countCharacters( document ) {
    const rootElement = document.getRoot();

    return countCharactersInElement( rootElement );

    // Returns length of the text in specified `node`
    //
    // @param {module:engine/model/node~Node} node
    // @returns {Number}
    function countCharactersInElement( node ) {
        let chars = 0;

        for ( const child of node.getChildren() ) {
            if ( child.is( 'text' ) ) {
                chars += child.data.length;
            } else if ( child.is( 'element' ) ) {
                chars += countCharactersInElement( child );
            }
        }

        return chars;
    }
}
```

You can check how it works here – https://jsfiddle.net/pomek/kb2mv1fr/.

Comment: how would you limit the count to something like 20 words?

Answer (score -1):

CKeditor has its own built in function for retrieving data in a text editor:

```
textbox_data = CKEDITOR.instances.mytextbox.getData();//mytextbox is id of textarea
```

Then you could just use the string object's length property:

```
alert(str.length);
```

Comment: The question was about CKEditor 5 and your answer is about CKEditor 4. Besides, this is not going to get you the number of characters, but a length of HTML data (including `<p>` tags, etc.)